# Getting error while executing selenium ide test case using .xml file

Tags: selenium-ide

> [error] Unexpected Exception: [Exception... "The URI scheme corresponds to an unknown protocol handler" 
>   nsresult: "0x804b0012 (NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL)" 
>   location: "JS frame ::  chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> 
>   file:///D:/SeleniumTestCases/UserExtensions/include.js?1426324803395 :: IDEIncludeCommand.prototype.getIncludeDocumentBySynchronRequest :: line 82" data: no]. toString -> function toString() { [native code] }, 
>    message -> , result -> 2152398866, name -> NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL, 
>   filename -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> 
>   file:///D:/SeleniumTestCases/UserExtensions/include.js?1426324803395, 
>   lineNumber -> 82, columnNumber -> 0, inner -> null, data -> null, 
>   stack -> IDEIncludeCommand.prototype.getIncludeDocumentBySynchronRequest@chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js
>   -> file:///D:/SeleniumTestCases/UserExtensions/include.js?1426324803395:82:4
>   xmlTestData.prototype.load@chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js ->
>   file:///D:/SeleniumTestCases/UserExtensions/datadriven.js?1426324803392:54:21
>   Selenium.prototype.doLoadTestData@chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js 
>   -> file:///D:/SeleniumTestCases/UserExtensions/datadriven.js?1426324803392:103:4
>   fnBind/retval@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js:60:11
>   ActionHandler.prototype.execute@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-commandhandlers.js:314:27
>   ._executeCurrentCommand@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-runner.js:306:18
>   TestLoop.prototype.resume@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-executionloop.js:78:12
>   fnBind/retval@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js:60:11
>   , location -> JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> 
>   file:///D:/SeleniumTestCases/UserExtensions/include.js?1426324803395
>   :: IDEIncludeCommand.prototype.getIncludeDocumentBySynchronRequest ::
>   line 82

I included all `js` file in `user-extension.js` text box
like `D:\SeleniumTestCases\UserExtensions\user-extension.js, D:\SeleniumTestCases\UserExtensions\sideflow.js,D:\SeleniumTestCases\UserExtensions\datadriven.js, D:\SeleniumTestCases\UserExtensions\include.js`

I referred my test case by [How can I read variables from data pool with selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250176/how-can-i-read-variables-from-data-pool-with-selenium-ide)

Answer (score 0):

sounds like improper xml file attempting to be loaded.
What is the selenium code causing this? how is the url written?